# Prove an inequality about $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Let $Q$ be the cube $$\{0\leq x_i \leq \sigma\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n,$$ and $u\in C^{1}(Q)$. Then
>   $$||u||_{L^2(Q)}^2\leq C\left[\frac{1}{\sigma^n}\left(\int_Q u(x) \ dx\right)^2+\sigma^2||u||^2_{H^1(Q)}\right]$$
>   where $C>0$ is a constant independent of $u$ and $\sigma$.

---

My attempt: I rewrite the above inequality. So it is equivalent to show that 
$$\int_Q|u|^2 \ dx\leq C\left[\left(\int_Q1\ dx\right)\left(\int_Q u(x) \ dx\right)^2+\sigma^2\left(\int_Q|u|^2 \ dx+\sum_i\int_Q\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right|^2\ dx\right)\right]$$
Then I don't know how to continue... I want to apply Poincare inequality here (since the first term on the right side looks like the average of $u$ over $Q$) but it seems it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me do it for $n=1$, and leave the extension to higher dimensions to you, so you can have some fun. Let 
$$
A = \frac1\sigma\int_0^\sigma udx
$$
be the average of $u$, and let $\xi\in[0,\sigma]$ be such that $u(\xi)=a$. Such $\xi$ exists because $u$ is continuous. Then we have
$$
u(x)=A+\int_\xi^xu'(t)dt
$$
which implies 
$$
|u(x)-A|\leq\int_0^\sigma|u'|\leq\sqrt\sigma\,\Big(\int_0^\sigma|u'|^2\Big)^\frac12
$$
or
$$
|u(x)-A|^2\leq\sigma\int_0^\sigma|u'|^2
$$
by Cauchy-Bunyakowsky-Schwarz. Proceeding further, we get
$$
|u(x)|^2\leq2A^2+2|u(x)-A|^2\leq2A^2+2\sigma\int_0^\sigma|u'|^2
$$
and integrating it over $x\in[0,\sigma]$ yields
$$
\int_0^\sigma|u|^2\leq2\sigma A^2+2\sigma^2\int_0^\sigma|u'|^2 = \frac2\sigma\Big(\int_0^\sigma u\Big)^2 +2\sigma^2\int_0^\sigma|u'|^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I think $||u||_{H^1(Q)}=||u||_{L^2}+||Du||_{L^2}$. So it seems that you have not proved the inequality...

Comment: @HaroldQ: I proved a stronger inequality. Please try to see that.

Comment: Now I see... I was stupid. Thanks!